# NFA: How does it function with empty-string moves?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

How does the NFA function on $\epsilon$ input if there is only a single $\epsilon$ string in the language?

I understand that $L^* = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty L^i$ where $L^0 = \{()\} = \{\epsilon\}$ and $L$ is the language.  The *empty string* $\epsilon$ is an input to a NFA with $\epsilon$ moves.

I suspect an infinite number of strings could be defined with $\epsilon$ anywhere in the order, then the NFA with $\epsilon$ moves would function. However I do not see this definition.

Comment: Are you talking about [Non-deterministic finite state machines (NFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)? I think you mean $\epsilon$ transition (an edge in the state machine graph with the label $\epsilon$) instead of $\epsilon$ move?

Comment: @plshelp that is correct, $\epsilon$ transition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one empty string, which you denoted by $\epsilon$. If you concatenate two empty strings, then you just get the empty string back: $\epsilon\epsilon = \epsilon$. This is the same as $0+0=0$. There is only one zero, and no matter how many times you add zero to itself, you only get the one zero.

I suspect that the real problem is with the semantics of $\epsilon$-NFAs (which are NFAs with $\epsilon$-transitions; an NFA is a nondeterministic finite state automaton). Let me give a definition which is similar to what you might have in mind. Suppose that $\Sigma$ is an alphabet which does not contain the symbol $\epsilon$, and define $\Sigma_\epsilon = \Sigma \cup \{\epsilon\}$. Here $\epsilon$ *does not* stand for the empty string. Rather, it is a letter of the alphabet. An $\epsilon$-NFA over the alphabet $\Sigma$ is the same as an NFA over the alphabet $\Sigma_\epsilon$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $\epsilon$-NFA over the alphabet $\Sigma$. Denote by $L_\epsilon(A)$ the language that it accepts as an NFA over the alphabet $\Sigma_\epsilon$. We define the language $L(A)$ over $\Sigma$, which is the language that $A$ accepts as an $\epsilon$-NFA over the alphabet $\Sigma$, as the language obtained from $L_\epsilon(A)$ by removing all $\epsilon$'s from all words.

For example, consider the following $\epsilon$-NFA $A$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$:

[image: Automaton created by https://madebyevan.com/fsm/]

The languages of this automaton are:
$$
L_\epsilon(A) = \epsilon^*(\epsilon a)^+ + \epsilon^*(\epsilon b)^+ \\
L(A) = a^+ + b^+
$$

Comment: Correct, clear, and concise!

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't understand the definition of the language accepted by an $\epsilon$-NFA. I gave one definition in my answer. You may be familiar with another definition. However, your mental image of how an $\epsilon$-NFA works is lacking. Choose one of the definitions, and adapt your mental image to match it.

Comment: Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton claims for an $\epsilon$-NFA, $\epsilon$ is an input symbol, but also claims $\epsilon$ transitions do not consume an input, which seems contradictory.  Given this, I would suspect your $\Sigma_{\epsilon}$ alphabet is really the one for the $\epsilon$-NFA.  A little confused here

Comment: Wikipedia is not a good source for mathematics.

Comment: @nick, as Yuval says, Wikipedia's mathematical pages are often low quality. But in this case, I think you are misreading the page. The page says "This automaton replaces the transition function with the one that allows the empty string ε as a possible *input.*" It does not say "possible input *symbol*"; the empty string ε is not a symbol any more than the input string `aa`. `aa` is a sequence containing two symbols; ε is a sequence of zero symbols.

Answer (score 4):

$\epsilon$ is a typographical convention, not a part of the underlying mathematical object. It's written where writing nothing would leave a confusing or ambiguous empty space.

Transitions labeled $\epsilon$ are really unlabeled transitions, and can be taken ad lib, without consuming any characters from the string. They don't consume an $\epsilon$ from the string. The string doesn't contain any $\epsilon$s, even if it's empty.

Comment: "" ..."are really unlabeled transitions"..."without consuming any characters from the string".  So an indefinite amount of $\epsilon$ transitions can occur between symbols from the input alphabet?

Comment: '"$\epsilon$ is the computer-science version of "this space intentionally left blank"' This  statement is **misleading** if not simply wrong. A whitespace character, which implies "this space intentionally left blank" literally, is not the empty string at all.

Comment: @JohnL. Okay, I reworded.

Comment: @Nick That's correct.

Comment: @benrg if an indefinite number of e-moves is allowed, how does the nfa know to read the next non-e input?  I can see where $\epsilon$ is in the input alphabet then a finite number of e-transitions can occur between the other input symbols because the sequence of $\epsilon$ between other symbols is finite.

Comment: @Nick NFAs use angelic nondeterminism: they take whatever legal transitions lead to an accepting state at the end of the string. Or, equivalently, they both take and don't take all legal transitions, remembering a set of reachable nodes at each string position. If there's a cycle of $\epsilon$ transitions, the set simply contains all nodes in the cycle.